# De onde vem o "Papai Noel"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Não, creio que o [“Papai Noel”](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/papai) não vem do Polo Norte, vem talvez do Brasil...

[*Noel* (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/noel) é uma palavra que está nos dicionários, mas com um significado diferente:

> **[Artilharia]**  Peça cilíndrica e oca, de madeira, que se introduz no meio do petardo, quando este se carrega.

Segundo a [etimologia de *Noel* (Etymoline)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=noel), é uma palavra de origem francesa (por sua vez de origem Latina - *natalis*).

Então como e porque razão o “Papai Noel” aparece no Brasil? E o “Papai Natal” também existe?

Comment: Eu chutaria que é uma mistura do pai Natal português com o Noël francês.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pelo que apurei o pai Natal português e o papai Noel brasileiro aparecem mais ou menos na mesma altura.

Comment: Concordo com o  @bfavaretto

Comment: No Brasil para a maioria das pessoas Noel é só o nome do velhinho de barba branca e vestido de vermelho não tendo nenhuma relação com a palavra Natal.

Comment: @bfavaretto Afinal o nome *Noel* aparece mais cedo que *Natal*, e *Noel* também aparece em Portugal. Não tinha procurado *pai Noel*, e tinha-me esquecido que no Brasil se escreveu *papae* até 1940.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Papai Noel***, como o tdmsoaes já averiguou (ver outra resposta), é uma adaptação do francês. Segundo a [Wikipédia, o *Père Noël*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A8re_No%C3%ABl)  (literalmente, *Pai Natal*) aparece na literatura francesa em meados do século XIX, correspondendo ao [*Father Chirstmas* britânico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Christmas) e ao [*Santa Claus* dos Estados Unidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus#Origins), sendo este nome uma adaptação do Sinterklaas (São Nicolau) holandês.

Luís da Câmara Cascudo conta-nos no seu [*Dicionário do Folclore Brasileiro*](http://www.slideshare.net/edgararruda/dicionario-do-folclore-brasileiro-camara-cascudo) que *Papai Noel* chegou ao Brasil na segunda década do século passado, tendo-se vulgarizado depois dos anos trinta, por «iniciativa oficial e letrada, jamais popular».

Mas já se encontra *Papai Noel* (ou *papá* ou *papae*) na imprensa brasilieira a partir de 1898:

[image]
[“Chronica”, *Gazeta de Noticias*, Rio de Janeiro, 25 de dezembro de 1898, p. 1.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=103730_03&pesq=papai%20noel&pasta=ano%20189)

Encontram-se na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://bndigital.bn.gov.br/hemeroteca-digital/) cerca de 70 ocorrências de *papai Noel* entre 1900 e 1909, contra 420 na década seguinte). Também se encontra esporadicamente ***papai Natal***, logo a partir de 1899:

[image]
[“Chroniqueta”, *Gazeta de Noticias*, Rio de Janeiro, 24 de dezembro de 1899, p. 2.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=103730_03&pesq=papai%20natal&pasta=ano%20189)

Em Portugal a primeira ocorrência de *pae Natal* no Google Books é em [1911 pela pena de Antero de Figueiredo na revista portuense *A Águia*](http://purl.pt/12152/1/j-2223-b_1911-02-Q1/j-2223-b_1911-02-Q1_item2/j-2223-b_1911-02-Q1_PDF/j-2223-b_1911-02-Q1_PDF_24-C-R0150/j-2223-b_1911-02-Q1_0000_capa-II_t24-C-R0150.pdf) (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Porque emquanto vocês esperavam pela vinda do **Pae Natal**, carregado de brinquedos e *bombons*

*Pai Noel* aparece também em Portugal. O primeiro exemplo que encontrei foi no semanário humorístico [*Sempre Fixe* de 13 de Janeiro de 1927 (p. 6)](http://hemerotecadigital.cm-lisboa.pt/Periodicos/SempreFixe/1927/Janeiro/N36/N36_master/SempreFixeN36.PDF):

> No Governo Civil, ante um mascarado descalço, de «**Pai Noel**»:
>   —Como explica esse disfarce?
>   —Aproveitando a tradição desta noite preparava-me para *recolher* calçado.

E parece que ainda por cá continuou (em Portugal) uns tempos. Veja-se a queixa na revista [*Portucale: Revista de Cultura* em 1940:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=UABXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pai%20noel%22&dq=%22pai%20noel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiosJLPzYLRAhWKshQKHVY9DUU4MhDoAQiCAjAm)

> O presépio desapareceu, desapareceu o Menino-Jesus, e lá de fora veio, para os substituir, a «árvore do Natal » e o « **Pai Natal** », também por aí chamado « **Pai Noël** »! E as lojas, pelo Pôrto fora, ostentavam a « árvore » e o « **Pai Noël** », cobertos de neve, muita neve

Portanto parece que o senhor foi importado de França para o Brasil e Portugal mais ou menos na mesma altura. Em Portugal acabou por ficar *pai Natal*; no Brasil vingou *papai Noel*.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o site [Só Portugues](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/curiosidades/papai_noel.php), como foi citado, *Noël* em francês significa ‘Natal’.

> Você sabia que o termo “Papai Noel” é uma herança da forma francesa
>   "Père Noël"?

Adaptado ao português a palavra francesa virou *Papai Noel*, tendo o sentido de ‘Papai Natal’.

> O nome “Santa Claus”, como Noel é conhecido em inglês, é uma adaptação
>   de “Sinterklaas”, forma como São Nicolau era chamado pelos holandeses,
>   que levaram suas tradições natalinas para colônias na América.